# how to change Java nio SSLBytechannel to ByteChannel

Tags: java, ssl, nio

Hi have the code bellow that allows to upgrade a bytechannel to SSL.

Does anyone knows how to revert the process? I want to be able to upgrade or downgrade the java nio bytechannel, or change the channel without closing the socket.

Write now im using the following code to upgrade the byte channel. I ask you expertize to create an reverse function. Please.

//call

```
ByteChannel sslbytechannel = upgradeChannel2ServerSSLChannel(sourcebytechannel);


//function

    private ByteChannel upgradeChannel2ServerSSLChannel(ByteChannel channel) {
        try {
            if (log.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
                log.fine("Switching socket to SSL");
            }

            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            File kf = new File(getExproxy().getKeystoreFilename()); 
            ks.load(new FileInputStream(kf), getExproxy().getKeystorePassword());

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, getExproxy().getKeystoreKeysPassword());

            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            tmf.init(ks);

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

            SSLEngine engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
            engine.setUseClientMode(false);
            engine.beginHandshake();

            return new SSLByteChannel(channel, engine);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception during server SSL channel upgrade", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

//Class

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.channels.ByteChannel;
    import java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngineResult;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
    import java

x.net.ssl.SSLSession;

/**
 * Upgrade a ByteChannel for SSL.
 *
 * <p>
 * Change Log:
 * </p>
 * <ul>
 *  <li>v1.0.1 - Dead lock bug fix, take into account EOF during read and unwrap.</li>
 *  <li>v1.0.0 - First public release.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * <p>
 * This source code is given to the Public Domain. Do what you want with it.
 * This software comes with no guarantees or warranties.
 * Please visit <a href="http://perso.wanadoo.fr/reuse/sslbytechannel/">http://perso.wanadoo.fr/reuse/sslbytechannel/</a>
 * periodically to check for updates or to contribute improvements.
 * </p>
 *
 * @author David Crosson
 * @author david.crosson@wanadoo.fr
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
public class SSLByteChannel implements ByteChannel {
    private ByteChannel wrappedChannel;
    private boolean closed = false;
    private SSLEngine engine;

    private final ByteBuffer inAppData;
    private final ByteBuffer outAppData;

    private final ByteBuffer inNetData;
    private final ByteBuffer outNetData;

    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());


    /**
     * Creates a new instance of SSLByteChannel
     * @param wrappedChannel The byte channel on which this ssl channel is built. 
     * This channel contains encrypted data.
     * @param engine A SSLEngine instance that will remember SSL current
     * context. Warning, such an instance CAN NOT be shared
     * between multiple SSLByteChannel.
     */
    public SSLByteChannel(ByteChannel wrappedChannel, SSLEngine engine) {
        this.wrappedChannel = wrappedChannel;
        this.engine = engine;

        SSLSession session = engine.getSession();
        inAppData  = ByteBuffer.allocate(session.getApplicationBufferSize());
        outAppData = ByteBuffer.allocate(session.getApplicationBufferSize());

        inNetData  = ByteBuffer.allocate(session.getPacketBufferSize());
        outNetData = ByteBuffer.allocate(session.getPacketBufferSize());
    }


    /**
     * Ends SSL operation and close the wrapped byte channel
     * @throws java.io.IOException May be raised by close operation on wrapped byte channel
     */
    public void close() throws java.io.IOException {
        if (!closed) {
            try {
                engine.closeOutbound();
                sslLoop(wrap());
                wrappedChannel.close();
            } finally {
                closed=true;
            }
        }
    }


    public SSLByteChannel(ByteChannel wrappedChannel) {
        this.wrappedChannel = null;
        this.engine = null;


        inAppData  = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
        outAppData = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);

        inNetData  = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
        outNetData = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
    }



    /**
     * Is the channel open ?
     * @return true if the channel is still open
     */
    public boolean isOpen() {
        return !closed;
    }

    /**
     * Fill the given buffer with some bytes and return the number of bytes
     * added in the buffer.<br>
     * This method may return immediately with nothing added in the buffer.
     * This method must be use exactly in the same way of ByteChannel read
     * operation, so be careful with buffer position, limit, ... Check
     * corresponding javadoc.
     * @param byteBuffer The buffer that will received read bytes
     * @throws java.io.IOException May be raised by ByteChannel read operation
     * @return The number of bytes read
     */
    public int read(java.nio.ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws java.io.IOException {
        boolean eofDuringUnwrap = false;
        if (isOpen()) {
            try {
                SSLEngineResult r = sslLoop(unwrap());
                if (r==null) eofDuringUnwrap = true;
            } catch(SSLException e) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "SSLException while reading", e);// TODO : Better SSL Exception management must be done
            } catch(ClosedChannelException e) {
                close();
            }
        }

        inAppData.flip();
        int posBefore = inAppData.position();
        byteBuffer.put(inAppData);
        int posAfter = inAppData.position();
        inAppData.compact();

        if (posAfter - posBefore > 0) return posAfter - posBefore ;
        if (isOpen())
            return (eofDuringUnwrap)?-1:0;
        else 
            return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Write remaining bytes of the given byte buffer.
     * This method may return immediately with nothing written.
     * This method must be use exactly in the same way of ByteChannel write
     * operation, so be careful with buffer position, limit, ... Check
     * corresponding javadoc.
     * @param byteBuffer buffer with remaining bytes to write
     * @throws java.io.IOException May be raised by ByteChannel write operation
     * @return The number of bytes written
     */
    public int write(java.nio.ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws java.io.IOException {
        if (!isOpen()) return 0;
        int posBefore, posAfter;

        posBefore = byteBuffer.position();
        if (byteBuffer.remaining() < outAppData.remaining()) {
            outAppData.put(byteBuffer);  // throw a BufferOverflowException if byteBuffer.remaining() > outAppData.remaining()
        } else {
            while (byteBuffer.hasRemaining() && outAppData.hasRemaining()) {
             outAppData.put(byteBuffer.get());
            }
        }
        posAfter = byteBuffer.position();

        if (isOpen()) {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    SSLEngineResult r = sslLoop(wrap());
                    if (r.bytesConsumed() == 0 && r.bytesProduced()==0) break;
                };
            } catch(SSLException e) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "SSLException while reading", e); // TODO : Better SSL Exception management must be done
            } catch(ClosedChannelException e) {
                close();
            }
        }

        return posAfter - posBefore;
    }


    public  void writeclean(java.nio.ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws java.io.IOException {


        if (isOpen()) {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    wrappedChannel.write(outAppData); 
                }
            } catch(SSLException e) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "SSLException while reading", e); // TODO : Better SSL Exception management must be done
            } catch(ClosedChannelException e) {
                close();
            }
        }


    }



    private SSLEngineResult unwrap() throws IOException, SSLException {
        int l;
        while((l = wrappedChannel.read(inNetData)) > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10); // Small tempo as non blocking channel is used
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        inNetData.flip();

        if (l==-1 && !inNetData.hasRemaining()) return null;

        SSLEngineResult ser = engine.unwrap(inNetData, inAppData); 
        inNetData.compact();

        return ser;
    }

    private SSLEngineResult wrap() throws IOException, SSLException {
        SSLEngineResult ser=null;

        outAppData.flip();
        ser = engine.wrap(outAppData,  outNetData);
        outAppData.compact();

        outNetData.flip();
        while(outNetData.hasRemaining()) {
            int l = wrappedChannel.write(outNetData); // TODO : To be enhanced (potential deadlock ?)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);  // Small tempo as non blocking channel is used
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        outNetData.compact();

        return ser;
    }

    private SSLEngineResult sslLoop(SSLEngineResult ser) throws SSLException, IOException {
        if (ser==null) return ser;
        //log.finest(String.format("%s - %s\n", ser.getStatus().toString(), ser.getHandshakeStatus().toString()));
     //   System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s\n", ser.getStatus().toString(), ser.getHandshakeStatus().toString()));
        while(   ser.getHandshakeStatus() != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.FINISHED
              && ser.getHandshakeStatus() != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NOT_HANDSHAKING) {
            switch(ser.getHandshakeStatus()) {
                case NEED_TASK:
                    //Executor exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                    Runnable task;
                    while ((task=engine.getDelegatedTask()) != null) {
                        //exec.execute(task);
                        task.run();
                    }
                    // Must continue with wrap as data must be sent
                case NEED_WRAP:
                    ser = wrap();
                    break;
                case NEED_UNWRAP:
                    ser = unwrap();
                    break;
            }
            if (ser == null) return ser;
        }
        switch(ser.getStatus()) {
            case CLOSED:
                log.finest("SSLEngine operations finishes, closing the socket");
                try {
                    wrappedChannel.close();
                } finally {
                    closed=true;
                }
                break;
        }
        return ser;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

With regular HTTPS requests, you cannot start talking plain text, then switch to SSL, then back to plain text.  You have to commit to either plain text or SSL mode of communication.

The only real life implementation that I can think of that allow upgrading plain text to SSL is STARTTLS with ESMTP.  But even then you cannot downgrade back to plain text, once the SSL connection is established.

So, unless you are rolling your own server protocol, there is no real need for SSL downgrading.

**EDIT**
pseudo-code for falling back to unencrypted communication

```
ByteChannel sslByteChannel = upgradeChannel2ServerSSLChannel(sourceByteChannel);

try
{
    doSslPortion( sslByteChannel );

    doPlainPortion( sourceByteChannel );
}
finally
{
    sourceByteChannel.close( );
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the reply in this case im using a client application that behaves like this. This client connects to multiple destinations, some of the servers are protocol specific, are able to talk ssl but the first reply is always plain text. It means that the client that i am integrating must start with ssl then expect the reply in plain text.

Comment: @user2505009.  You need to keep a copy of `sourcebytechannel` in your system, and when you finish with the SSL portion of your protocol, just use `sourcebytechannel`.  It will be good for reading unencrypted data.  Make sure you do not close `sslbytechannel` before reading unencrypted data.  After reading unencrypted data, close `sourcebytechannel`

Comment: Thanks Alexander, can you post some code to show how it works? i dont know what you mean by a copy, but in my tests if i create something like
ByteChannel clone = (ByteChannel)source;
before upgrading to SSL the result is always the existing object.Maybe im doing something wrong? Using my code above can you show me your idea?

Comment: Im able now to keep a copy of the source bytechannel using your reply, but when writing with the plain channel it returns
SSL: Unsupported record version Unknown-48.48 i need to first close the ssl session before writing, im trying with engine.closeOutbound(); but with no luck. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak do you have a working SSL engine implemented and tested?